vue-splide repeated (cloned) slides are not working (static)
I'm using vue3 + splide (https://splidejs.com/). When I set the type to "loop" and slides are repeated, cloned slides are "static" (they do not receive any vue lifecycle callbacks such as onMounted or even @click events)
eg)
<template>
  <Splide :options="options">
    <SplideSlide v-for="id in buttons">
      <button @click="onClick(id)">{{ "Button " + id }}</button>
    </SplideSlide>
  </Splide>
  <div>{{ text }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from "@splidejs/vue-splide";
import { ref } from "vue";
import "@splidejs/splide/dist/css/themes/splide-default.min.css";
const options = { type: "loop", perPage: 3, height: 200 };
const text = ref<string>("");
const buttons = ["button1", "button2"];
const onClick = (id: string) => (text.value = `${id} clicked`);
</script>

example is available on https://codesandbox.io/s/72-forked-j4r47z?file=/src/App.vue
when you click the third button, it the onClick even't won't be fired, since this is a "clone" of the first button. Is there a way to force splide to create vue component instead of DOM clone?
Thanks

Yes, I am aware.  The problem is splider "cloning" existing slides to fill slots. If I have to guess, it's cloning DOM directly (bypassing vue). updated what i see  above.

At this point it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. I gave you a working alternative to mounted (an event which fires each time the active slide changes), rather than only the first time a slide becomes active. Isn't this what you wanted to know? And, to answer your comment, Splider is not cloning anything, nor is it  bypassing Vue. It takes the items array and displays them based on index. What confuses Vue is the fact that you're not providing a :key with v-for. I'm pretty sure you'll find a Vue warning in console about it. Use a unique identifier (e.g: uuid).

@tao Splide is cloning slides when used in loop mode. And yes it is by-passing vue because it straight up clones the dom nodes and no Vue code is being run, and not only is there no reactivity but also no intialization
